# Two styles in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, styles, android-developer-api

I want to create a **fortepiano**, so white and black buttons are code in themes and night themes.
But these two themes don't work:

[image]

I wrote in **activity_main** `style="@style/KeyboardKeyWhite"` and `style="@style/KeyboardKeyBlack"`

[image]

But at the final result this like this (when white theme turn on):

[image]

or this (when dark theme turn on):

[image]